# How to test if class instance is instance of class that it extends?

Tags: coffeescript

```
class A
class B extends A

b = new B
b instanceof B # true
b instanceof A # false
```

How I can check that `b` is "also" instance of `A` (because `B` extends `A`)

Comment: I don't understand your question, `b instanceof A` returns `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A
class B extends A

b = new B
console.log "b is an instance of extended class " if b instanceof B # b is an instance of extended class 
console.log "b is an instance of extended class A because B extends a " if b instanceof A # b is an instance of extended class A because B extends a
```

You can simply use:

```
if b instanceof B && b instanceof A  #B is instance of A and B classes
  console.log "B is instance of A and B classes"
```

Here is the code snipt: 
http://repl.it/meN/1